# Youtube video embeded doesnt show

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

From youtube i copied the embedded code given then pasted it into my website. However whenever I load the website instead of appearing at the bottom of the page in the given table space it appears as a blank space at the top of the webpage. I have tried this with multiple videos and still the same thing happens or instead it shows a box to the width and height coded with the message "file is not in your directory"

Here is the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Josh Taylor</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
<h1 class="PageHeader"> JOSH TAYLOR</h1>
<div id="navigation">
<ul class="Navigation">
  <li><a href="index.html" class="thispage"> HOME </a></li>
  <li><a href="Music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
  <li><a href="Film.html">FILMMAKING</a></li>
  <li><a href="Photo.html">PHOTO</a></li>
  <li><a href="Justified.html"> JUSTIFIED DESIGN </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content">

<table width="50%" border="0" align="center" class="table">
<tr>
  <td class="table"><span class="PageTitle">Filmmaking and Video editing</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="table"><p class="Introduction">In watching hours of videos on YouTube,  TV shows and       Films I got inspired to create my own content through filming video  and editing the clips by the use of video editing software.</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="table"><span class="H1">Short films</span>
    <p>For the past couple of years I  have enjoyed going out with my friends and filming small films that are usually  action-based and generally experimenting with my camera which I bought around a  year ago. I used to film on a old family digital camera however decided on  getting a DSLR camera to suit both my Filmmaking and Photograph hobbies. I  recently went on a trip to London and filmed 250 small clips all between 1-10  seconds long where I am currently editing all the clips together to create a  montage of my experience.</p>
    <p><img src="../GFX/FreddieW.jpg" width="620" height="350"></p>
<h1 class="H1"> VFX</h1>
  <p>VFX stands for Visual effects and  is a large part of what inspired me to get involved with  filmmaking and video  editing. FreddieW and Corridor Digital are two major channels on YouTube that  create short films that always involve visual effects in their videos created  by them in software such as Adobe after effects. I have been watching FreddieW  for many years and the channel has over 1 billion total views on all his  videos. They inspired me in that these effects were possible from my own  computer and therefore I have continued to practice and learn visual effects  software such as after effects.</p></td>


</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="table"></td>
  <iframe width="640" height="360"      
 src="//www.youtube.com/embed/H0Ib9SwC7EI?feature=player_detailpage"
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</tr>
</table>
<h1 class="H1">&nbsp;</h1>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<h3 class="PageFooter"> JOSH TAYLOR - 2014 </h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS stylesheet

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #000;
}

#header {
background-color: #000;
clear: both;


}

#content {
background-color: #FFF;
float: none;
clear: both;
font-family: "Futura LT Light";
font-size: 16px;
text-align: center;
text-indent: 0;
padding-left: 0%;
background-image: url(../GFX/Background2.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
}

.PageHeader {
font-family: "Code Bold";
font-size: 50px;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
background-color: #000;
}
#navigation ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}


.Navigation {
font-family: Futura-Heavy;
font-size: 18px;
color: #FFF;
}

.PageFooter {
font-family: "Futura LT Light";
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFF;
text-align: left;
}


#navigation {
background-color: #666;
float: none;
clear: both;

}
#footer {
background-color: #000;
clear: both;
padding-left: 15%
}
.maintext {
font-family: "Futura LT Light";
font-size: 24px;
font-style: normal;
color: #000;

}
.H1 {
font-family: Futura-Heavy;
font-size: 36px;
}
#navigation a {
text-align: center;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 20%;
background-color: #000;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
}


#navigation a:hover, #navigation a:active, #navigation a:focus, #navigation a.thispage {
background-color: #43a6cb;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
}
#Hyperlink a:hover, #Hyperlink a:active, #Hyperlink a:focus, #Hyperlink a.thispage {
color: #43A6CB;
}


.H2 {
font-family: Futura-Heavy;
font-size: 30px;
}
.PageTitle {
font-size: 40px;
font-family: Futura-Heavy;
color: #000;
}
.Introduction {
font-family: "Futura LT Light";
font-size: 20px;
}


.H3 {
font-family: Futura-Heavy;
font-size: 24px;
}
.Hyperlink {
font-family: Futura-Heavy;
font-size: 18px;
color: #666;
text-decoration: none;
}
.Hyperlink a:hover, .Hyperlink a:active, .Hyperlink a:focus, .Hyperlink a.thispage {
color: #43A6CB;
}
```

[Here is a screenshot of what happens when loaded!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSr3w.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the iframe inside of the `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

yes it should be put inside td 
but youtube addres is also not correct

in iframe src address **http:** is missing

replace iframe code with this one

```
<iframe width="640" height="360"      
 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/H0Ib9SwC7EI?feature=player_detailpage"
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```